# how can i check if the iterator come to the end of list?

Tags: c++, iterator, listiterator

i have this code:
and i want on the function run on all over the list and print it

but i don't want to send the list to the function

i want to send only the iterator

but the problem it the on the "for" i cant do

```
it_mylist != it_mylist.end()
```

what can i do please?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <list>

void f(list<int>::iterator it_mylist)
{       
    for (; it_mylist != it_mylist.end(); ++it_mylist)
    {
        cout << *it_mylist;
    }  
}
void main()
{   
    list<int> mylist;
    mylist.push_front(1); mylist.push_front(2); mylist.push_front(3); 

    list<int>::iterator it_mylist = mylist.begin();
    f(it_mylist);  
}
```

Comment: The way standard libraries (like the STL) are designed is to have functions that take a couple of iterators as an argument: void f(list<int>::iterator begin, list<int>::iterator end) (I do not think you can avoid passing either 'end' or the list as an argument).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a pair of iterators, one to the beginning and the other to the end of your list:

```
void f(list<int>::iterator first, list<int>::iterator last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        cout << *first;
    }
}

// In main()
f(begin(mylist), end(mylist));
```

Comment: that i know to do
but i need send only 1 iterator that point on begin

Comment: @dani1999 There is no way to know where the end of the list is if you only pass one iterator to your function. You need to either pass a pair of iterators, an iterator and a count, or a reference to the list itself.

Comment: @dani1999 so your requirements are impossible?

Comment: i dont know
i still check